How to grant SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN permission to master MySQL user or rds_superuser_role from MySQL Workbench hosted on RDS?
Using MySQL 8.0.39 on an AWS RDS insteance, for troubleshooting purposes we want to be able to Enable/Disable the global general_log setting , being able to turn it on and off easily and quickly from MySQL Workbench.
We'd rather *not *do this in the AWS Console (RDSADMIN); that method is not very flexible.
To be clear -- this question is not asking how to enable general_log via a parameter group change, as is discussed in this other thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8722565/how-do-i-get-access-to-the-mysql-logs-from-a-rds-instance    -- this we can already do.
We want to use set global general_log = 'on' (or 'off') from Workbench, which is supported by MySQL if the user has proper privs.
The problem is one of privs/permissions.

set global general_log = 'on' says we need SUPER or SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN privs to run it

Trying to GRANT SYSTEM_VARIBLES_ADMIN to the master user (and rds_superuser_role), but both require RDSADMIN USER privs or it gives Access denied.


GRANT SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN ON *.* TO rds_superuser_role@% WITH GRANT OPTION
yields

Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the RDSADMIN USER privilege(s) for this operation

The question: what's the process to add SYSTEM_VARIABLES_ADMIN priv to our master user?  Ideally using Workbench or AWS Console.  I promise I've tried finding the answer in various online resources for quite a while now, but to no avail.
HELP?

What does AWS Support say?

i doubt that it is even possible
